# Create a .zip file under a parent directory through Unix commands which contains only the parent folder and its sub folders

Tags: unix

I have a folder structure

```
Parent Folder (folder name for e.g.: SMX)
----Folder 1
----Folder 2
----Folder 3
----File 1.
```

I want to create a zip file inside parent folder which contains all the files and folders under the parent folder. My final folder structure should look like this

```
Parent Folder
----Folder 1
----Folder 2
----Folder 3
----File 1
----SMX.zip (Zip file contains folder1, folder2,folder3, file1).
```

Is there any command in unix that achieves this functionality? Also the parent folder is not present in current working directory. It is present under some other location (folders) where we have to traverse and perform this operation.

Comment: Just run `zip -r SMX.zip .` on `Parent Folder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to the parent folder using `cd ParentFolder` and call `zip -r yourzipfile.zip *`.

This will create a ZIP file with **recursive** added folders. The asterisk will match everything inside the current folder. Maybe you need to install the `zip` command before. That depends on your distribution.

Comment: Hi Knut - I am writing the following statement in commanda prompt but some how it is not working - cd /abc/ParentFolder && zip -r SMX.zip *. Is there any problem in syntax? I am new to unix so appreciate your help. By the way Zip command was not installed before. I have installed it and trying but it is not working.

Comment: Nope, thats fine… What exactly does not work?

Comment: I think I am changing directory and zip the folder at the same time..May it this is the issue but still not sure. I split the statement into two separate statements and it worked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the real problem is, but wondered if you mean you want to create the zip without leaving your current folder, if so, use this:

```
( cd "/path/to/Parent Folder" && zip -r SMX.zip . )
```

Comment: The Problem is resolved. What I did is I wrote two separate Unix Commands.cd "/path/to/Parent Folder and then Zip -r SMX.zip. It worked for me.